# Change innerHtml of div according to value of model item in view .NET6 EF6 Razor Pages No MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Change innerHtml of div according to value of model item in view
.NET6 EF6 Razor Pages No MVC

I am trying to have a due date optional in a todo list.
Since date fields are not nullable/required, I set the default due date to 09/09/9999.
That date represents a todo that does not have a due date.
What I want is to have the innerHtml of that due date display "None" if the due date is 09/09/9999.

My code however shows "None" in the due date div in the table of only the first row, regardless of the date.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7SMt.png)

Here is the javascript code

```
function hideDueDate () {
const dueDateDiv = document.querySelector('#due-date');

if (dueDateDiv.innerHTML = "09/09/9999") {
    dueDateDiv.innerHTML = "None";
    }   
}

hideDueDate();
```

And here is the view.

```
    <tbody>
         @*READ*@
            @foreach(var obj in Model.ToDo)
            {
             <tr>
                <td width="10%">@Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", obj.CreateDate))</td>
                <td width="20%">@obj.Name</td>
                <td width="40%">@obj.Description</td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <div id="due-date">@Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", obj.DueDate))</div>
                </td>
                <td width="20%" class="">
                    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <input asp-for="@obj.Complete" class="form-check-input mt-3" type="checkbox" readonly="readonly" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="w-65 btn-group" role="group">
                    <a asp-page="View" asp-route-id="@obj.Id" class="btn btn-outline-info rounded-pill mx-2">
                        <i class="bi bi-binoculars">&nbsp;View</i>
                    </a>
                    <a asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="@obj.Id" class="btn btn-outline-success rounded-pill mx-2">
                        <i class="bi bi-pencil-square">&nbsp;Edit</i>
                    </a>
                    <a asp-page="Delete"  asp-route-id="@obj.Id" class="btn btn-outline-danger rounded-pill mx-2">
                        <i class="bi bi-trash-fill">&nbsp;Delete</i>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
             </tr>
            }
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.`document.querySelector('#due-date')` can only get the first matched element. You need use `.each()`.

2.The condition should be `dueDateDiv.innerHTML == "09/09/9999"`.

Change your code like below:

```
function hideDueDate () {
    $('div #due-date').each(function() {
        if(this.innerHTML=="09/09/9999"){
            this.innerHTML= "None";
        }
    });
}
```